# How to define PHY mode and MAC mode between back to back switches

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, phy, mac, rgmii

I'm planning to use this [Switch](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002112B.pdf) IC connected to another another switch ic which is the same part number. When connecting these devices in back to back mode with RGMII interface between then, I need to define which switch is PHY and which would be MAC right?

In that case, can someone tell me how to do it? In the datasheet, mentioned in page 12, I don't see a strap option that can help to identify this switch as PHY or MAC.

Comment: Well, they are on page 12. How can we help you to see it, have you tried searching with CTRL-F?

Comment: @Justme, that's only for MII/RMII interfaces. I want to know which is the strap option for the RGMII interface. If you see on page 12, the LED3[1,0] option, defines the GMAC interface. In my case, it is RGMII. But the next strap, LED2_1 defines whether the GMAC is in PHY mode or MAC mode. But this strap seems to be mentioned only for MII/RMII/GMII interfaces. I am confused. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

The [KSZ8795CLX-EVAL Board User’s Guide](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/KSZ8795CLX-EVAL_User%20Guide%20v1.0.pdf) section *4.6 GMII/RGMII/MII/RMII Ports Configuration* contains:

> 4. Two KSZ8795CLX-EVAL boards with back to back connection for GMII/RGMII access.
>
>    a). One can be set to SW5-GMII MAC mode, another one set to SW5-GMII PHY mode.
>
>    b). One can be set to SW5-RGMII with Gbps or Mbps mode, another one set to SW5-RGMII with Gbps or Mbps mode, the connection Figure shows below.

Which suggests when using the RGMII interface that MAC / PHY mode doesn't apply.

[Application Note Using Two KSZ8795CLX Family Switches for a Non-blocking Max 8 ports Fast Ethernet Switch](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/App%20Note-Using%20Two%20KSZ8795CLX%20family%20devices%20for%20a%20max%208-port%20non-blocking%20Ethernet%20Switch.pdf) shows two back-back KSZ8795CLX connected using RGMII:
[image]

In the application note are other tables which shows the strap settings for the RGMII ports:
[image]

And how to connect the signals:
[image]

From the question:

> When connecting these devices in back to back mode with RGMII interface between then, I need to define which switch is PHY and which would be MAC right?

Based upon the above information in the Microchip (ex Micrel Inc.) the answer is **No**, since in RGMII mode the concept of PHY / MAC mode doesn't apply.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in the RGMII interface, the TXC and RXC has to be sourced by the corresponding PHY or MAC right? In that case, should we define which device would act as PHY and which would act as MAC between the devices?

Comment: @Freshman Looking at _Connection Signals for Port 5 MAC 5 SW5-RGMII Interface_ from the app note in the answer in RGMII mode: KSZ8795CLX 'A' GTXC5 is connected to KSZ8795CLX 'B' GRXC5, and KSZ8795CLX 'B' GTXC5 is connected to KSZ8795CLX 'A' GRXC5. I.e. the clocks between the KSZ8795CLX's are cross-connected and can't see the need to define which device is PHY and which is MAC. Perhaps you could try contacting Microchip support for confirmation as I'm an only answering by reading the Microchip documentation and don't have actual hardware to test.